# Javascript - defineProperty vs Prototype

Tags: javascript, function, prototype

I have just run into an unexpected problem whilst trying to create an array prototype for a function that emulates what is available in .net (linq) called SingleOrDefault().

Whilst the prototype function worked fine, I found that when iterating over a normal array using the following syntax *for (var x in y)*... my function name appeared as one of the properties and broke my logic.

As a result of some googling I have redefined the function (below).

My question is, is the code in the **Current** block the right way to extend the Array object without causing any unwanted side effects?

**Previous**

```
Array.prototype.singleOrDefault = function (predicate) {
    var items = applyPredicate(this, predicate);
    if (items.length > 1) {
        throw new Error(errorOutput.multipleElements);
    }
    return (items) ? items[0] : null;
};
```

**Current**

```
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'singleOrDefault', {
    value: function (predicate) {
        var items = applyPredicate(this, predicate);
        if (items.length > 1) {
            throw new Error(errorOutput.multipleElements);
        }
        return (items) ? items[0] : null;
    },
    enumerable: false
});
```

Comment: The second syntax is relatively new. Depending on what sort of browser support you need/expect it might not be very practical.

Comment: Just don't use `for (var x in y) {...}` as it is not intended to be used with array but with objects only. [for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

Comment: @Andreas One of the gotchas with that is that you never know if a library does it unless you read through the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes your 'current' code is correct, not as supported with older browsers as the previous code which is a downside if you need ie6/7 support (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty).

You could use the object.hasOwnProperty method with the 'previous' code to achieve the same effect when you are iterating:

```
for (var x in y) {
     if (y.hasOwnProperty(y[x])) {
        //would filter out SingleOrDefault in your examples above
    }
}
```